# how to customise Drupal's ImageZoom module

Tags: image, drupal-7, drupal-modules, zooming

I'm using version 7.x-2.0-beta2

Included in the module is *imagezoom.api.php*

From what I understand; this is the file you apply any [customisations](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/configuration) to the image zoom functionality.
I assume you have to copy this file into your own site specific templates directory to protect it from being overwritten during any module update.

So the original is in *sites/all/modules/imagezoom/imagezoom.api.php*

I have taken a copy and moved it to *sites/all/themes/[my_site_name]/templates/system/imagezoom.api.php*

But the changes I make to this file are not reflected on the site.
(I have tried the changes in both path locations)

The function within this file is simply:

```
function hook_imagezoom_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
  // Change the border color to red
  $settings['borderColour'] = '#f00';
  $settings['responsive'] = TRUE;
}
```

Can anyone tell me where this file has to be placed in order for the module to pay attention to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [create a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules) and then simply create a function in the mymodule.module file which replaces the hook function, like this:

```
function mymodule_imagezoom_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
  // Change the border color to red
  $settings['borderColour'] = '#f00';
  $settings['responsive'] = TRUE;
}
```

Replace whatever you want from the function above, clear your caches and you should be good to go.

In the link I provided above, look deeper at the "[Implementing your own hook](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/writing-comments-and-implementing-your-first-hook)" section if you are still having trouble.

Once you have the hook working, you can use the dpm function to view the current values that the page can see. The devel module needs to be on for this to work. In your case, you probably want to do this:

```
dpm($settings);
```

and modify the values from there.

Comment: Thanks... the method you've suggested gets the function noticed.  It still isn't making a difference to the final screen output, but at least I know Drupal is finding it and running the function !